# How do I use Bindings.bindContent?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a polygon that I want to grow in size when the window is resized. I have a DoubleBinding that it the baseline for the size of all of my shapes in the scene. I use this DoubleBinding to create a ListBinding that calculates how big the polygon should be. I tried to use Bindings.bindContent(list1, list2) to bind the ListBinding to the polygon's points, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon();

    ListBinding<Double> trianglePoints = new ListBinding<Double>() {
        {
            super.bind(width, height);
        }
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Double> computeValue() {
            ObservableList<Double> points = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            points.addAll(0.0, 0.0, width.get()/2, height.get()/4, 0.0, height.get()/2);
            return points;
        }
    };
    Bindings.bindContent(triangle.getPoints(), trianglePoints.get());
```

I found that if I add an InvalidationListener to the triangle points and manually change the the polygon points when it fires off, it works.

```
    trianglePoints.addListener((InvalidationListener)(listener) -> triangle.getPoints().setAll(trianglePoints.get()));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your binding in following way:

```
Bindings.bindContent(triangle.getPoints(), trianglePoints);
```

Your previous binding did not work because `trianglePoints.get()` is just result of `computeValue()` call i.e. creating `ObservableList` with some values calculated upon initial `width` and `height`. Thus further changes to `width` and `height` properties were not taken into account.

Comment: I actually am using @fabian 's solution, but when I tried your solution, the points didn't update unless I did something like call `System.out.println(trianglePoints.get())` to get the `trianglePoints` to update. I only had to call it once (ie right after the binding), after which it updated as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not using a `ListBinding`. You do not need to recreate the list over and over again, you just need to modify some of the points:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon(
            0, 0,
            0, 0,
            0, 0);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(triangle);

    root.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldH, newH) -> {
        double h = newH.doubleValue();
        triangle.getPoints().set(3, h / 4);
        triangle.getPoints().set(5, h / 2);
    });

    root.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldW, newW) -> {
        double w = newW.doubleValue();
        triangle.getPoints().set(2, w / 2);
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Furthermore it's also possible to do this using the scale properties (unless you're using a stroke or some exotic fill):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon(
            0, 0,
            0.5, 0.25,
            0, 0.5);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(triangle);

    triangle.scaleXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
    triangle.scaleYProperty().bind(root.heightProperty());

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```